# Can KrakenD validate access keys sent in the body rather than header

Tags: krakend, snowplow

I have a usage tracking library(snowplow) which needs to send data to a kinesis stream collector. We are using KrakenD in the middle  for api gateway.
Inorder to secure this, I need to pass access token. Snowplow at present does not allow custom headers at the present, which prevents me from sending this data. Is there an option in KrakenD which allows it to validate a token sent in the body rather than the header?

Answer (score 1):

KrakenD JWT validation expects you to send the token data in the `Bearer` header or inside a cookie. You cannot validate a token sent in the body.

I don't understand what is the problem of Snowplow not accepting custom headers. The validation would occur on KrakenD side and KrakenD does not send any custom header to Snowplow unless you explicitly add them in the `input_headers` list. If you have more information, I'd be happy to assist.